# In Objective-C how to deal with NSArray of related objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, subclassing

`Animal` is a class with a `BOOL` property called `alive`. `Monkey`, `Zebra` and `Walrus` are sub-classes of `Animal`. If I have an instance of an `NSArray` called `zoo` containing a mix of instances of `Monkey`, `Zebra` and `Walrus`, and I'd like to find the first alive `Zebra` instance, I might do something like this:

```
Zebra *zebra; 
for (Animal *animal in zoo) {
    if ([animal isMemberOfClass:[Zebra class]] && animal.alive) {
        zebra = animal;
        break;
    }
}
```

Problem is the compiler complains about incompatible pointer types when I set `zebra = animal`. If I do some casting like `zebra = (Zebra *)animal` then it seems to work, but I'm not sure that kind of casting is safe in Objective-C.

What is a better way of dealing with situations like this?

Comment: That type of casting is fine here, because you have tested `anmimal` for its beeing of type `Zebra`. Anyway, `isKindOfClass` may be saver on the long run as that would return YES for every potential (future) subclass of `Zebra` too.

Comment: `Zebra`, the way your example is written, is undefined if there are no `Animal` instances in the collection that are both class `Zebra` and `alive`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're experiencing an "is a" problem.

If you had been assigning `zebra` to `animal`, there would have been no issue, since the class of `zebra` is `Zebra`, which "is a" `Animal`.

But with what you're doing, you're assigning `animal` to `zebra`, but `animal` is of class `Animal`, the superclass. The "is a" test fails, but a simple casting:

```
zebra = (Zebra *)animal;
```

takes care of the compiler warning. And yes, it's safe.

Here's a more modern way of doing the same thing. Incidentally, since, in the last line, `-objectAtIndex:` returns `id`, the aforementioned problem doesn't arise :

```
NSUInteger index = [zoo indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(Animal *animal, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return ([animal isMemberOfClass:[Zebra class]] && animal.alive);
}];
Zebra *zebra = (index != NSNotFound) ? [zoo objectAtIndex:index] : nil;
```

Note that I did tweak one of the arguments to the block from `id obj` to `Animal *animal`; if you know your collection contains only references to instances of `Animal`, you certainly can do this.

Comment: +1. The "modern" way is probably slower though. Its best case is *O(n)*, which is equal to the OP code worst case. Looping and breaking will be more performant in any case, with the only exception of the `zebra` object being found in the last iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Thats definitely the way to do it in objective-C. If youre checking that its the kind of class your casting to first, its very safe. Even if its "typed" to something else, `isMemberOfClass` uses the runtime to report what it *really* is.

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do same task.

```
[zoo enumerateObjectsusingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
    if ([obj isMemberOfClass:[Zebra class] && animal.alive){
        zebra = (Zebra *)animal;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

BTW, this way of casting is safe.